# Jmeter - Need to use radom integer values in the payload JSON value for POST API while executing

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

can someone please help me I am new to JMeter.

I am executing a POST API with a payload JSON data which is present externally.
while executing the POST API through JMeter HTTP request. the JSON payload value will be fetched dynamically with FilesUpload option in the HTTP request.

I have given the Payload JSON data path in the file path.

My doubt is how can I change a random value in JSON Payload dynamically while executing the POST API.

Can someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

As of [JMeter 5.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-1-released-td5728235.html) you cannot use [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in the files you're providing via `Files Upload` tab, to wit you can, however JMeter will not evaluate/resolve them in the runtime, you need to go for one of the following solutions:

1. Use [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) to load the file from disk, amend the necessary parameter(s) and write it back. See [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) for more details
2. Build a multipart POST request manually like it's described in [Testing REST API File Uploads in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter). In this case you will be able to put [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) directly into the file body and read the file from disk using [__eval()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) and [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) functions combination.